# EF Append to an IQueryable a Where that generates an OR

Tags: entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to achieve dynamic filtering on a table. My UI has filters that can be enabled or disabled on demand, and as you can imagine, my query should be able to know when to add filters to the query.

What I have so far is that I check if the filter object has a value, and if it does it adds a where clause to it. Example:

```
var q1 = DBContext.Table1

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterModel.SubjectContains))
    q1 = q1.Where(i => i.Subject.Contains(filterModel.SubjectContains));

if (filterModel.EnvironmentId != null)
    q1 = q1.Where(i => i.EnvironmentId == filterModel.EnvironmentId);

if (filterModel.CreatedBy != null)
    q1 = q1.Where(i => i.CreatedByUserId == filterModel.CreatedBy);

var final = q1.Select(i => new
                    {
                        IssuesId = i.IssuesId,
                        Subject = i.Subject,
                        EnvironmentId = i.EnvironmentId,
                        CreatedBy = i.CreatedByUser.FullName,
                    });

return final.ToList();
```

The code above generates T-SQL that contains a `WHERE` clause for each field that uses `AND` to combine the conditions. This is fine, and will work for most cases.

Something like:

```
Select 
    IssueId, Subject, EnvironmentId, CreatedById 
From 
    Table1 
Where
   (Subject like '%stackoverflow%') 
   and (EnvironmentId = 1) 
   and (CreatedById = 123)
```

But then I have a filter that explicitly needs an `IssueId`. I'm trying to figure out how the EF `Where` clause can generate an OR for me. I'm looking something that should generate a Tsql that looks like this:

```
Select 
    IssueId, Subject, EnvironmentId, CreatedById 
From 
    Table1 
Where 
    (Subject like '%stackoverflow%') 
    and (EnvironmentId = 1) 
    and (CreatedById = 123)
    or (IssueId = 10001)
```

Comment: Take a look at [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Ivan for your suggestion. Unfortunately it still generated an AND when looking at the SQL Profiler.

Comment: I meant, instead of chaining **multiple** `Where` (which produces `AND`), you have to build **single** `Where` with `AND`, `OR` combinations using that predicate (i.e. `Expression<T, bool>>`) helper class. Read the whole topic. Unfortunately in order to be used in EF you'll need the whole `LinqKit`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this that doesn't have to do multiple database call and works for me.

```
//filterModel.StaticIssueIds is of type List<Int32>
if (filterModel.StaticIssueIds != null)
{
    //Get all ids declared in filterModel.StaticIssueIds
    var qStaticIssues = DBContext.Table1.Where(i => filterModel.StaticIssueIds.Contains(i.IssuesId));

    //Let's get all Issues that isn't declared in filterModel.StaticIssueIds from the original IQueryable
    //we have to do this to ensure that there isn't any duplicate records.
    q1 = q1.Where(i => !filterModel.StaticIssueIds.Contains(i.IssuesId));

    //We then concatenate q1 and the qStaticIssues.
    q1 = q1.Concat(qStaticIssues);
}

var final = q1.Select(i => new
    {
        IssuesId = i.IssuesId,
        Subject = i.Subject,
        EnvironmentId = i.EnvironmentId,
        CreatedBy = i.CreatedByUser.FullName,
    });

return final.ToList();
```